# DevExpress Style Application behavior messed up after being open for 4 hours

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, devexpress

I don't know if anybody had encountered this issue but I have this VB app which has to be left open for hours and it updates form elements every 30 seconds. I used DevExpress WinForm styles   for this app and I set the LookAndFeel to "Whiteprint" Theme.

After a few hours when I hover the mouse over to the Ribbon Menu all elements in that section blink for a few seconds and some other panels in the form are gone and replaced by red borders and a cross inside them.

I have no idea why such thing would happen. Any clues ?

Comment: Post some image to make us understand

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to determine the cause of this issue due to the lack of information. In most cases, the problem is caused by incorrect use of background threads in the application.

I believe you can start to find a suitable solution to your issue in the [Big red X: A control becomes crossed with red lines after an exception](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A884) KB article.

Then you can try to [search the similar issues](https://search.devexpress.com/?q=red%20cross&p=T4%7CP1%7C28&d=15) at [DevExpress Support Center](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center).

If it does not help you, please contact the DevExpress [directly](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Create).

Comment: I do have a BackgroundWorker in my project. I just removed it and put its tasks directly in a Timer. I will run and test it for a few hours. I hope that will do it.